# Get Action, Controller and Area Name in Library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dll

I have an MVC3 Project and a Library(.dll) project included some of my codes, So I need in library project to get area, controller and action name, I use the following lines in MVC project:

```
string areaName = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] ?? "Root";
string controllerName = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
string actionName = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

but in library Project I haven't any access to `Request` object, either when I add `using System.Web.Mvc;`

```
public static void GetNames(){

  //string areaName = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] ?? "Root";
  //string controllerName = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
  //string actionName = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

}
```

So, how can I get this names in Library project?

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to pass them as arguments, not have the class library fetch them because in this way you are strongly coupling your class library with a web application.

But if you insist on getting them you will have to use the `HttpContext.Current` which I do not recommend:

```
var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var rd = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
string controller = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
string action = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
```

Comment: Ok, but how about area? I use `string area = rd.Values["area"] as string;` And `string area= rd.GetRequiredString("area");` none of them worked.

Comment: `rd.Values["area"] as string` should work. If it returns nothing it is because you are not inside an area.

Comment: I thought like you, but i try it in mvc project and library, in mvc return me correct value but in library always return null, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: rd.Values["area"] as string doesn't work. You have to use rd.DataTokens["area"] to get a value back